# Rails3: how to reload a page with a parameter taken from a collection_select within the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, collections

I have a page with a route in the form : :client_id/tarif/:tarif_name

in the corresponding HTML page, I have a <%= collection_select(.....:tarif_name...) which enables to select the name of the tarif to be shown. That works.

How do I instruct to reload the page with the new :tarif_name parameter in the url ?

I thought of using the :onchange option helper with collection_select, but although I managed to execute javascript this way, I find no example of composing and triggering the loading of a url through that option.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to run javascript code in the :onchange, then window.location.href = "your_url" will make the redirect.

You will also need the selected value. Your onchange will be something like

```
function() {
  window.location.href = "your_url" + this.value
}
```

Comment: That worked marvels! Thank you very much for a very good reply!
The only thing I miss now is how to insert the :client_id parameter in the "your_url"

Comment: I just realized, while testing, that window.location.href = this.value is sufficient (without "your_url"), as this.value is just appended to the :client_id/tarif/... route, through some magic...

Comment: simple and ugly thing to do is: window.location.href = document.URL + "/" + this.value PS don't forget to choose the right answer :)